# conditional check in Ansible iosxr_config module

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to run a config from j2 onto IOSXR on checking a cond
ition

- name: conf
  iosxr_command:
    commands: "show run interface Bundle-Ether 1234"
  register: reg

  - name: put j2 on iosxr
    iosxr_config:
    src: templates/abc.j2
    when : '" string" in reg.stdout'

I don't get any errors but it always says the condition is false even though it is not supposed to .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You used the quotes incorrectly in your conditional:

```
when: "string" in reg.stdout
```

The syntax of "when" can be a bit confusing as it is different from everywhere else, so here are some notable things you might find helpful:

- " " around the entire conditional are optional, but never use ' '
- any strings need to be in " " or ' '
- everything that is not surrounded by " " or ' ' is interpreted as either a keyword (i.e. in) or a variable (i.e. reg.stdout). You can use filters with those variables, but you should surround the variable and the filters with ( )

Comment: If I try that way I get the following error message    ```This one looks easy to fix.  It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote.  For instance:

    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout" ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I did was correct. I was checking wrong string in the condition .